# TeamCity has failed to start

Tags: teamcity

On starting TeamCity from URL, I get following error :

[image]

It was working fine till last week. And when opened today, it is showing error.
I logged in as administrator to view logs. Below is the stacktrace :

```
  <pre>jetbrains.buildServer.processes.ProcessTreeTerminatorException: Process has not exited within 30 seconds
at jetbrains.buildServer.processes.ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.readCommandOutput(ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.java:159)
at jetbrains.buildServer.processes.ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.buildProcessTree(ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.java:315)
at jetbrains.buildServer.processes.ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.getProcessVisitor(ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.java:82)
at jetbrains.buildServer.processes.ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.getCurrentPid(ProcessTreeTerminatorImplBase.java:28)
at jetbrains.buildServer.processes.ProcessTreeTerminator$1.getCurrentPid(ProcessTreeTerminator.java:144)
at jetbrains.buildServer.processes.ProcessTreeTerminator.getCurrentPid(ProcessTreeTerminator.java:101)
at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.StartupProcessor.createPidFile(StartupProcessor.java:476)
at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.StartupProcessor.doInitialStage(StartupProcessor.java:326)
at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.StartupProcessor.processConcreteStage(StartupProcessor.java:83)
at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.StartupProcessor.processConcreteStageSafe(StartupProcessor.java:503)
at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.StartupProcessor.processTeamCityLifecycle(StartupProcessor.java:558)
at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.StartupProcessor.access$000(StartupProcessor.java:92)
at jetbrains.buildServer.maintenance.StartupProcessor$1.run(StartupProcessor.java:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Some more information :

**Current Startup State**

**Startup status**

Current step: TeamCity server startup error

Next step: not defined yet

**Data Directory**

Data Directory path is not specified/detected yet

**Database**

Not connected to the database yet.

**Versions**

Software version: 722

Data directory version: unknown

Database version: unknown

**Logs**

Logs path: C:\TeamCity\logs

What should be done to resolve error?

Comment: Why are you using an EAP build?  I'd recommend switching as they've fully released 9.1 now.

Also, what database are you using?  The internal one or an external?  A full log may help figure out where in the startup process the error has occurred.  Can you provide the full log?

Answer (score 4):

As this is an EAP build, you should report this issue to JetBrains with complete information logs [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Reporting+Issues)